# Python - Creating a Reversed String Using a For Loop

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I'm trying to figure out how to create a reversed string using a for loop. It's to my understanding that this isn't the most efficient way of doing it but my assignment's parameters specify that you have to use a for loop. I have what seems like it should work but I keep getting the error: "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" for "line 7, in ReverseString test2 = test1(n)".

```
def ReverseString(test1):
    global test2
    test2 = ""
    for n in range (len(test1)-1, -1, -1):
        test2 = test1(n)
        print (test2)
        return test2

#Input

test1 = input("Enter a string to test if it is a Palindrome: ")

ReverseString(test1)
```

Comment: The TypeError is telling you exactly what and where the problem is.  What do you expect to happen with `test2 = test1(n)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to call the string as you see in the error message by `test1(n)` you want to *index* the string by doing `test1[n]`.

Also, your return is inside the loop you want it to be outside, and you want to use `+=` to concatenate instead of reassigning it on every iteration.

I'm assuming this is an exercise and thats why you're doing this iteratively. Nonetheless, for the sake of completeness to reverse a string you can just do `test1[::-1]`

Answer (score 1):

```
def ReverseString(test1):
    test2 = ""
    for i in range (len(test1) - 1, -1, -1):
        test2 += test1[i]
    return test2

test1 = input("Enter a string to test if it is a Palindrome: ")

print(ReverseString(test1))
```

calling a string makes no sense, what you want is to append each character from `test1` to `test2`, and your return must be outside of the loop